# Revealing source code after javascript executes

Tags: c#, winforms

Following the discussion over at:

[WebBrowser and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604722/webbrowser-and-javascript/9607652#comment12230780_9607652)

It was revealed that the "view source" is different than the actual page after javascript execution, because "view source" is what the server sent to the browser and does not account for any javascript changes that happened on the page.

As you know already, the WebBrowser.DocumentText shows the same source as "view source" in a browser.

So my question is, what is the proper way (if any) to show the actual source code after any javascript has executed?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe this will help though it has no accepted answers.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635948/c-sharp-webbrowser-control-get-document-elements-after-ajax